# Why is conversion from JSON-LD to Turtle in rdflib not working?

Tags: python, rdf, json-ld, rdflib, turtle-rdf

I am trying to make a simple script which converts JSON-LD to Turtle, and from Turtle to JSON-LD on demand.

So far, I was using rdflib, and the Turtle -> JSON-LD part is working fine. I give some context header and a Turtle file, and it produces valid JSON-LD.

However, the way back is not working:

```
from rdflib import Graph

g = Graph()


#input file name and file format here
g.parse(location=r'C:\Users\franken\PycharmProjects\rdf_tools\LD_conversion\input\test_converted.json', format='json-ld')

#output file name and file format here

g.serialize(destination=r'C:\Users\franken\PycharmProjects\rdf_tools\LD_conversion\output\testbacktoturtle.ttl', format='turtle')
```

So far, pretty simple code, just a direct use of rdflib.

However, this produces the error:

```
C:\Users\franken\PycharmProjects\rdf_tools\LD_conversion\input\test_converted.json does not look like a valid URI, trying to serialize this will break.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\franken\PycharmProjects\rdf_tools\LD_conversion\main.py", line 24, in <module>
    g.parse(location=r'C:\Users\franken\PycharmProjects\rdf_tools\LD_conversion\input\test_converted.json', format='json-ld')
  File "C:\Python311\Lib\site-packages\rdflib\graph.py", line 1470, in parse
    source = create_input_source(
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Python311\Lib\site-packages\rdflib\parser.py", line 416, in create_input_source
    ) = _create_input_source_from_location(
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Python311\Lib\site-packages\rdflib\parser.py", line 478, in _create_input_source_from_location
    input_source = URLInputSource(absolute_location, format)
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Python311\Lib\site-packages\rdflib\parser.py", line 285, in __init__
    response: addinfourl = _urlopen(req)
                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Python311\Lib\site-packages\rdflib\parser.py", line 272, in _urlopen
    return urlopen(req)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Python311\Lib\urllib\request.py", line 216, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Python311\Lib\urllib\request.py", line 519, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Python311\Lib\urllib\request.py", line 541, in _open
    return self._call_chain(self.handle_open, 'unknown',
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Python311\Lib\urllib\request.py", line 496, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Python311\Lib\urllib\request.py", line 1419, in unknown_open
    raise URLError('unknown url type: %s' % type)
urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error unknown url type: c>

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I don't understand why this error is occurring, it seems to be trying to access a url, which is not valid. The input data looks like this (note that this input is actually the output of a rdflib conversion of a valid turtle file into this json-ld) All I'm doing is trying to make the conversion circle whole again:

```
{
  "@context": {
    "@context": {
      "@bio": "<https://bioschemas.org/>",
      "@ex:": "<http://example.com/ns#>",
      "@owl": "<http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>",
      "@qudt": "<http://qudt.org/schema/qudt/>",
      "@rdf": "<http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>",
      "@rdfs": "<http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>",
      "@schema": "<http://schema.org/>",
      "@sd": "<https://w3id.org/okn/o/sd#>",
      "@sh": "<http://www.w3.org/ns/shacl#>",
      "@skos": "<http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#>",
      "@spe": "<https://openschemas.github.io/spec-container/specifications/>",
      "@xsd": "<http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>"
    }
  },
  "@id": "https://www.blabla.com/SUBJECT_AREA",
  "@type": "https://blabla.px_variable.com",
  "http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#prefLabel": {
    "@language": "en",
    "@value": "SUBJECT AREA"
  },
  "http://www.yourprefix.ch/isDefinedAs": [
    {
      "@language": "en",
      "@value": "A definition of something, in english in this case."
    },
    {
      "@language": "fr",
      "@value": "Une definition de quelquechose"
    },
    {
      "@language": "it",
      "@value": "Una “definizione di qualcosa"
    },
    {
      "@language": "de",
      "@value": "Eine Definition von etwas"
    }
  ]
}
```

It feels a bit like I'm missing something obvious, or some parameter which prevents rdflib from actually trying to open URL's (after all, a URL should not HAVE to be resolvable for it to still be valid JSON).
I have tried running the conversion with and without context, and also different json-ld files, but the error remains consistent.

I'm using rdflib 6.3.2 on python 3.11 on Windows.
Any tips welcome!

Comment: `json-ld`, `json-nl`, `ndjson` are names describing the common practice of writing a *single* JSON document per line *without newlines* in the document itself. What you posted is a fully formatted and indented JSON document instead

Comment: The [parse docs](https://rdflib.readthedocs.io/en/stable/apidocs/rdflib.html#rdflib.graph.Graph.parse) show the path should be passed as the `source` parameter, not location. Try using `g.parse(thatPath)` or `g.parse(source=thatPath)` instead of `location`. It's a good idea to use a pathlib `Path` object instead of a string too

Comment: Thanks for your quick responses. I have tried both your suggestions, without success. (I should have added I tried also omitting the location/source flag completely) .

Converting my formatted json-ld to a single string using https://w3percentagecalculator.com/json-to-one-line-converter/ also did not change the error message I'm getting.

But thank you for the suggestions, eventually something will stick hopefully! :)

Comment: It's not a matter of making things stick. You need to actually find out what's wrong in order to fix it. Have you tried with a *relative* path, eg just `test_converted.json`? Store the file next to the script and try with a relative path. Or create a sample json and try to load it. You need to isolate the problem first. Is it the path? The content?

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem with the latest version of `rdflib` and [the JSON in this example](https://rdflib.readthedocs.io/en/stable/apidocs/rdflib.html#rdflib.parser.PythonInputSource) which isn't JSON-LD either. I tried with a `StringIO` source, relative *and* absolute paths, both as Path objects and string. So this isn't the path, and `json-ld` also covers *JSON*

Comment: I cant reproduce the problem with this JSON either. `g.parse(json_path, format='json-ld')` works without an issue

Comment: So, it seems that the problem lies in the reading of the JSON-LD file, since if I put the contents of the file into a variable called "stuff", and then use parse(data=stuff) it works. Going to explore further into the directions you suggest.

Comment: I tried with the question's string and can't reproduce any problem even when I pass the path to `location`. Which rdflib version are you using? Did you post the *actual* code that fails?

Comment: I'm using rdflib 6.3.2 on python 3.11 on Windows, and yes, this was the actual code that fails.

Comment: Same, I installed it just now. No error.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254379/discussion-between-robin-and-panagiotis-kanavos).

Comment: Trying the JSON-LD in the [Playground](https://json-ld.org/playground/), I get "jsonld.SyntaxError: Invalid JSON-LD syntax; a @context @id value must be an absolute IRI, a blank node identifier, or a keyword.". The context looks quite weird ‒ why are the URIs in `<`...`>` and names prefixed with `@`? That's not how one would write a context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't reproduce any problem. I'm using Python 3.11 on Windows 11, with rdflib 6.3.2 installed just now.

This code writes the JSON string into a file :

```
json_path=r'C:\Projects\testbacktoturtle.json'

json='''{
  "@context": {
    "@context": {
      "@bio": "<https://bioschemas.org/>",
      "@ex:": "<http://example.com/ns#>",
      "@owl": "<http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>",
      "@qudt": "<http://qudt.org/schema/qudt/>",
      "@rdf": "<http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>",
      "@rdfs": "<http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>",
      "@schema": "<http://schema.org/>",
      "@sd": "<https://w3id.org/okn/o/sd#>",
      "@sh": "<http://www.w3.org/ns/shacl#>",
      "@skos": "<http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#>",
      "@spe": "<https://openschemas.github.io/spec-container/specifications/>",
      "@xsd": "<http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>"
    }
  },
  "@id": "https://www.blabla.com/SUBJECT_AREA",
  "@type": "https://blabla.px_variable.com",
  "http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#prefLabel": {
    "@language": "en",
    "@value": "SUBJECT AREA"
  },
  "http://www.yourprefix.ch/isDefinedAs": [
    {
      "@language": "en",
      "@value": "A definition of something, in english in this case."
    },
    {
      "@language": "fr",
      "@value": "Une definition de quelquechose"
    },
    {
      "@language": "it",
      "@value": "Una “definizione di qualcosa"
    },
    {
      "@language": "de",
      "@value": "Eine Definition von etwas"
    }
  ]
}'''


with open(json_path,"w",encoding="utf-8") as f:
    f.write(json)
```

This code loads it and converts it succesfully:

```
from rdflib import Graph

g = Graph()

g.parse(location=json_path, format='json-ld')

#output file name and file format here

g.serialize(destination=r'C:\Projects\testbacktoturtle.ttl', format='turtle')
```

Comment: Thank you for your patience. The problem lied in the fact that the file that Python was looking for in not present in the folder I pointed it to. The error message of course was not super helpful in finding that mistake, but I guess it's a trivial one.

Comment: [Path.exists()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.exists) could help with that. Yes, the error isn't helpful.